Vite app deploying problem with react-toastify
When I am deploying my Vite app. It shows the problem
error during build:
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css" from "/opt/render/project/src/admin/src/App.jsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`

I have explored various approaches and attempted to deploy my project on Vercel, Netlify, and Render. However, I encountered the same error on all of these platforms. I have uninstalled and then reinstalled react-toastify. Please help me, it is frustrating. Also, there is another thing, my project has 3 folders frontend, backend and admin panel. React-Toastify is working smoothly in the Admin Panel, but in the front end, it's not working. I have attached some images for your reference. I have attached both the front end and admin panel for better understanding. Feel free to ask me anything you want.
package.json frontend
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.27.0",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.47",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13",
    "vite": "^5.4.1"
  }
}


package.json Admin
{
  "name": "admin",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.27.0",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.47",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13",
    "vite": "^5.4.1",
    "vite-plugin-style-import": "^2.0.0"
  }
}


App.jsx Admin Panel
App.jsx Frontend
